# Using jQuery, how to locate an element when the Name and Value are known

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Thanks for reading this

I thought I could use find(), but couldn't make it work. I know I can add IDs or classnames, but would like to know how with the current markup.

Thanks

Here is the HTML

```
<input name="keywordCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="S" />
<input name="keywordCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="C" />
<input name="keywordCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="A" />
```

and the js

```
<script language="Javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

 $(function(){
  $('[name="keywordCheckbox"]').bind("click",
   function() {
    if($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
     switch(this.value) {
      case "A":
       var $_this = $(this) ;
       $('[name="keywordCheckbox"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != $($_this).val()) { $(this).attr("checked",false); }
       });
       break ;
      default:
 DOESN'T WORK --> $('[name="keywordCheckbox"]').find('[value="A"]').attr("checked", false);}
      } // END Switch
    } // END If
  }); // End BIND
 }); // End eventlistener
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?
I think you are trying to uncheck the checkbox with value 'A', but this is not how it’s done.

Check http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue

Comment: sorry, I can see how it was unclear. I think my answer clears up my intent. Were you saying the way I uncheck the input is incorrect? I'd be interested in your solution..the link didn't give me another solution

Comment: Yes. The code you used in the line you marked with “DOESN'T WORK” in the source above can not work, as to my knowledge there is no attribute or method _false_ in whatever object attr(name) returns. The way you do it in the solution you posted below with attr(key,value) is what I meant to suggest.

Comment: sorry, I didn't catch that. Thanks. I edited my question

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to chain the attribute selectors:

```
 $('input[name="keywordCheckbox"][value="A"]').attr("checked",false);
```

Will set checked to false for the input with name keywordCheckbox and value of A.

```
 $('input[name="keywordCheckbox"][value!="A"]').attr("checked",false);
```

will set checked to false for the inputs with name keywordCheckbox whose values are not A.

**EDIT**

I just tested the following in Firefox/Macintosh with the latest jQuery.  Works fine.  What version of jQuery are you using?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('input[name=keywordCheckbox]').bind( 'click', function() {
       if (this.checked) {
          if (this.value == 'A') {              
             $('input[name="keywordCheckbox"][value!="A"]')
                .attr("checked",false);
          }
          else {
             $('input[name="keywordCheckbox"][value="A"]')
                .attr("checked",false);
          }
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: my apologies, I tested your code and it worked fine. originally, you had a ^ instead of a ! for the negative test, but I thought I had tested it both ways...maybe I included a space between the [name] and [value]..anyway I like your solution...gave an upvote and selected this answer

Comment: Yeah.  I noticed that typo and fixed it later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could do:

```
$("input[name='keywordCheckbox']").filter("input[value='A']")
```

Then there is no need for an each function.